# hyperref to line number in listing imported from file

Tags: listings, code

Can I refer to a line number from the imported file without escaping chars inside the file?

Say, I import my file like this

```
\lstinputlisting[language=c]{main.c}
```

and I want to `\hyperref{}` line 50 without modifying it or copying to my .tex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure that I understand. The whole point of using `\ref{...}` is to be able to dynamically refer to other parts of the document. From want you have said you simply want to refer to line 50 so why not write `by line 50`...?

Comment: @Andrew yeah, you are correct. What I actually want though is to hyperref this part of the document. Sorry for not asking this straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example sets a label for the listings by option `label`. The anchor name of the label is extracted and analyzed to get the internal listings number. In this case the unnumbered listings has anchor `lstlisting.-1` with the number `-1` for the listings. The anchor names for the line numbers follow the pattern `lstnumber.<listings number>.<line number>`. Macro `\lstlinelink` references the line, given the label for the listings and the line number. Two LaTeX runs are necessary because of the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}[2006/02/20]

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lstlinelink}[2]{%
  \refused{#1}%
  \edef\lstlinelink@tmp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
  \ifx\lstlinelink@tmp\@empty
    #2%
  \else
    \edef\lstlinelink@target{%
      \expandafter\lstlinelink@parse\lstlinelink@tmp\@nil
      #2%
    }%
    \hyperlink{\lstlinelink@target}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\def\lstlinelink@parse#1.#2\@nil{lstnumber.#2.}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Line~\lstlinelink{foo}{5} loads package \texttt{hyperref}
and the document starts at line~\lstlinelink{foo}{25}.
\lstinputlisting[
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  label=foo,
  numbers=left,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
]{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]